# I got stuck in a React-Redux/toolkit proyect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, redux-toolkit

I'v been working in an e-commerce app, i'm using:

//Front-End
React-js
Redux/toolkit
Material
Stripe

//Server
Firebase (Auth, Cloud Function, Firestore, ..etc)

I'm so proud of what i've done, but at this point i have more question than answer as the days go by:

When to use createAsyncThunk and when direct query:
Example: When i increase the quantity of a product on cart if i use createAsyncThunk it has a delay (understandable bacause is an asynchronos request), but when i make the same request with setDoc is way more fast.

Which steps i have to consider when im going to structure the data, i'v been searching for a good tutorial of it, but i didn't find any to fit my needs.